# SAS convert numeric variable to time

Tags: time, format, sas

I have a numeric variable where the numbers are of the form 924 1045 1742 etc. These are times.

I want to convert them to the time format 09:24:00.

I can't seem to find a way of doing this.

Comment: Are they in a SAS data set or text file?

Comment: They are coming from a csv

Answer (score 1):

Informat used is hhmmss and the format to see the time you want is time5:

```
data have;
informat time hhmmss4.;
format time time5.;
input time;
cards;
924
1045
1742
;
run;
```

IF the field is already a number in a dataset this would work:

```
data have;

input time;
cards;
924
1045
1742
;
run;

data want;
    set have;

    time_num=input(put(time, 4. -l), hhmmss4.);
    format time_num time5.;
run;

proc print;run;
```

Comment: Hi Reese. Thanks. I actually can't read in the CSV directly for some reason due to my connection so had to use the import function. I now have it as a SAS dataset with the time variable as a 8. numeric. I really don't understand the put/input stuff and not sure why this doesn't work DATA SET2;
 
SET scratch.JRA_UK_July_spot;
/*informat time hhmmss4.;*/
format time1 time5.;
time1=input(time, time5.);
run;

Comment: Sorry I realised I said it was from a csv but I actually need it do be from a SAS file.

Comment: After you've imported the csv file, press F4 from within an editor window and it should recall the code used to import the data.  You can then edit the informat and format according to the answer from @Reese